# Handling dynamic number of answers in prepared statement

Tags: php, database

on the frontend I am using JQuery Validate, and I pass the following to the backend

```
data: {
    'field1':  $("input[name='field1']:checked").val(),
    'field2':  $("input[name='field2']:checked").val(),
    'field3': $("#field3").val(),
    'field4' : $("#field4").val(),
    'field5' : $("#field5").val(),
    'field6' : $("#field6").val()
}
```

The first three fields are required, so they will always have a value.  The next three are optional, so they may not have a value.  In my PHP file, I do something like this for required fields

```
if (!empty($_POST["field1"])) {
    $field1 = filter_var($_POST["field1"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    array_push($inputArray, $field1);
} else{
    $errors['field1'] = 'Please select field1';
}
```

And for optional fields I do

```
if (!empty($_POST['field4'])) {
    $field4 = filter_var($_POST["field4"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    array_push($inputArray, $field4);
}
```

By the end of this, I have an `$inputArray` which may contain between 3-6 values which is passed to my database file.  Here, I am doing something like this

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO database_table(Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5, Field6) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $this->inputArray[0]);
```

Now that will be fine for the first three, but if I then try an optional element and its not there, an error will be thrown.

Whats the best way to handle this type of situation? In the PHP file, should I always push an empty value for the three if statements that are optional fields e.g.

```
else {
    array_push($inputArray, '');
}
```

I know off several solutions I could potentially use, just wanted to get opinions from others as to how they would handle it.

Thanks

Comment: you could build the prepared statement according to the data you actually want to insert? ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that the best way of handling this sort of problem is to dynamically build the query.  This sort of approach is easier when you use an associative `$inputArray`.  As such, instead of doing

```
array_push($inputArray, $field1);
```

Do

```
$inputArray['field1Name'] = $field1;
```

replacing "field1" with the appropriate value for each field.

That way you can build your query like this:

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO database_table(";
$qry .= implode(',', array_keys($inputArray)); //append a comma separated list of field names.
$qry .= ") VALUES("
$qry .= trim(str_repeat('?,', count($inputArray)), ','); //append ?, for each element in the array and trim the trailing comma
$qry .= ')';

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($qry);
$stmt->execute( array_values($inputArray)); //Execute the query with the values from the input array
```

In this way the number of arguments in the sql query is dynamic and based on the number of fields that were filled out.

This could be easily changed to use named parameters instead of `?` but the general concept is the same.